# How to get private key of a pkcs12 certificate that I created using keytool

Tags: cryptography, keytool

I created a pkcs12 certificate using keytool but it does not seem to have a private key. I need to use this certificate for establishing trust with a partner. When I use the certificate in .Net code I can see that the private key is null in the store and I get the error

```
Object contains only the public half of a key pair. A private key must also be provided.
```

My question is if it is possible to associate a private key with this certificate or should it have been generated only before creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to associate a private key with an existing certificate. If it was, the certificate would serve no purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used openssl tool to get the private key of the certificate and it has listed a private key. i am not sure how to make this key available in windows trust store.